# Support Tibetan vowel u by HarfBuzz?

Tags: harfbuzz

Does harfbuzz support Tibetan vowel u well? For usp and harfbuzz library，the shaped result is different for the same Tibetan chars.there are results:

usp:
[image: usp result]

harfbuzz:
[image: harfbuzz result]

The Tibetan chars is "U+0F45 U+0F74 U+0F74 U+0F74", string length is 4.

**i don't know why does the result differently,and how to fix it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HarfBuzz stacks diacritics for different scripts (Arabic also for example) and what you see is its difference with Uniscribe which doesn't have that feature so there isn't anything you should do in your side unless you insist on having that dotted circle for some strange reasons for some specific reason.

Comment: Thank you so much! There's another issue,If the chars before vowel u are Tibetan numbers or Tibetan end marker(U+0F0B,U+0F0D,U+0F0E), the vowels will also be stacked,Is that the same reason？

Comment: Yes. And hard to think which approach would be better.

Comment: OK,Thank you very much!